# 0auth 2.0 Obtaining an authorization code for Upwork API

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, graphql, postman, upwork-api

I'm trying to obtain an authorization code in order to use the Upwork API, using Oauth 2.0.

I send a GET request in the body using x-www-form-urlendcoded (have tried form-data as well) on Postman to "https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize" with 3 fields:
-response_type
-client_id
-redirect_uri

All of those fields should be correct as I take straight from the Upwork API key information they gave me and response_type directly from the documentation.

The response I get is a "403 Forbidden - The request was a legal request but the server is refusing to respond to it."

My best guess to the problem is it could have something to do with "X-Upwork-API-TenantId header" as it is mentioned in the docs but isn't mentioned anywhere in getting the auth code but I don't fully understand what it is/does.

docs: https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#getting-started-authentication

I was hoping to get a response like this as shown in the docs:

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta http-equiv="refresh"           content="0;url='https://upwork.com/ab/messages/rooms/?code=b094053c2892cb819942e2d01e7237e7'" />
                <title>Redirecting to https://upwork.com/ab/messages/rooms/?code=b094053c2892cb819942e2d01e7237e7</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                Redirecting to <a href="https://upwork.com/ab/messages/rooms/?code=b094053c2892cb819942e2d01e7237e7">https://upwork.com/ab/messages/rooms/?code=b094053c2892cb819942e2d01e7237e7</a>.
              </body>
            </html>
```

But am instead getting this without code=b094053c2892cb819942e2d01e7237e7 and a 403 forbidden response.

If anyone knows how I could obtain that access token for Oauth it'd be greatly appreciated.